# Unable to get touches in COCOS 2dx?

Tags: c++, sprite, cocos2d-x, ccsprite, touchesbegan

Below is my `HelloWorld.h` class:

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
public:
HelloWorld();

// Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
virtual bool init();

b2World* world;

// there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

// a selector callback
void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);

// implement the "static node()" method manually
CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

virtual void draw();
virtual void ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
void update(float dt);


};
```

And in my `HelloWorld.cpp` class i have initialized My `init` method

```
bool HelloWorld::init(){
setTouchEnabled( true );
setAccelerometerEnabled( true );
scheduleUpdate();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, 0, true);
return true;
}
```

This code is working for me now! :)

Comment: Hmmm just a guess, try removing the "virtual" keyword from the ccTouches* method declarations.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. :(

Comment: `cocos2d::CCLayer` is already derived from `cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate`, try to remove it from class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Targeted Delegate is for single touch events.  Change your events to something like this:

`virtual bool   ccTouchBegan (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)`

You can read up more about targeted and standard touch delegates on the iPhone side of the Cocos2D documentation at this [Link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips%3atouchdelegates?s%5B%5D=targeted&s%5B%5D=standard)

Writing the delegate in my initialisation method as per below solved the problem

```
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 1);
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code as a standard delegate to see if you can receive any touches?

Comment: No, i am very new to this programming! So i don't know what you exactly mean by this!

Comment: Get rid of the all the targeted delegate code and add this line:  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addStandardDelegate(this, 1);  Then see if you are getting into the ccTouchesBegan with a breakpoint.  Standard delegate should handle touches just like a regular app so you should get all touch events.

Comment: using this delegate i get an error ambiguous conversion from derived class hello world to cctouchdelegate

Comment: You got rid of ,public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate from your header right?  Can you post your whole init method.

Comment: I have edited my question and made the desired changes which can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable multiTouch capability you can use :

```
virtual bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchMoved(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent){}
virtual void ccTouchEnded(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent){}
```

And so you need to:

```
bool init()
{
    ...
    setTouchEnabled(true);
    this->setTouchMode(ccTouchesMode::kCCTouchesOneByOne); // Important
}
```

If you omit last line you will need to override these (multiTouch mode):

```
void ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
void ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
void ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet* touches, cocos2d::CCEvent* event);
```